# Explanation of function (int / byte array)

Tags: c

I can't understand this function.
Can you please help me?

```
   void write_int(unsigned char *str, int value)
    {
        str[0] = (unsigned char)(value);
        str[1] = (unsigned char)(value >> 8);
        str[2] = (unsigned char)(value >> 16);
        str[3] = (unsigned char)(value >> 24);
    }
```

Comment: Look up "bit shift" online

Comment: It writes an `int` to the address pointed to by `str` in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format, by means of [bit shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). This function is probably intended to run on a big endian platform which does not have native support for little endian.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will essentially convert an integer to a char array.

First, `int` generally has a sizeof 4 bytes (32bit).

Second, `>>` is a bit shift operator where `a >> b` shifts the number `a` right `b` times. `>>>` just makes sure that there are zeroes inserted on the left.

Third, when an `int` is placed into a `char` it truncates the most significant bits. That is we only keep the smallest 8 bits.

So this function places the smallest 8 bits into a char, then the next 8 bits and so on.

Comment: It is worth noting that on a big endian platform, the code posted by the OP does more than just "converting" an `int` to a `char` array. It also reverses the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), i.e. it writes the `int` in little endian format.